# What is the Rust equivalent of C++'s shared_from_this?

Tags: rust

I have an object that I know that is inside an `Arc` because all the instances are always `Arc`ed. I would like to be able to pass a cloned `Arc` of myself in a function call. The thing I am calling will call me back later on other threads.

In C++, there is a standard mixin called `enable_shared_from_this`. It enables me to do exactly this

```cpp
class Bus : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Bus>
{
....
   void SetupDevice(Device device,...)
   {
       device->Attach(shared_from_this());
   }
}
```

If this object is not under `shared_ptr` management (the closest C++ has to `Arc`) then this will fail at run time.

I  cannot find an equivalent.

EDIT:

Here is an example of why its needed. I have a timerqueue library. It allows a client to request an arbitrary closure to be run at some point in the future. The code is run on a dedicated thread. To use it you must pass a closure of the function you want to be executed later.

```
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use timerqueue::*;
use parking_lot::Mutex;
use std::sync::{Arc,Weak};
use std::ops::{DerefMut};

// inline me keeper cos not on github
pub struct MeKeeper<T> {
    them: Mutex<Weak<T>>,
}

impl<T> MeKeeper<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            them: Mutex::new(Weak::new()),
        }
    }
    pub fn save(&self, arc: &Arc<T>) {
        *self.them.lock().deref_mut() = Arc::downgrade(arc);
    }
    pub fn get(&self) -> Arc<T> {
        match self.them.lock().upgrade() {
            Some(arc) => return arc,
            None => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
}
// -----------------------------------

struct Test {
    data:String,
    me: MeKeeper<Self>,
}

impl Test {

    pub fn new() -> Arc<Test>{
        let arc = Arc::new(Self {
            me: MeKeeper::new(),
            data: "Yo".to_string()
        });
        arc.me.save(&arc);
        arc
    }
    
    fn task(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.data);
    }

    // in real use case the TQ and a ton of other status data is passed in the new call for Test
    // to keep things simple here the 'container' passes tq as an arg

    pub fn do_stuff(&self, tq: &TimerQueue) {
        // stuff includes a async task that must be done in 1 second

        //.....
        let me = self.me.get().clone();
        tq.queue(
            Box::new(move || me.task()),
            "x".to_string(),
            Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(1000),
        );
    }


}

fn main() {
    // in real case (PDP11 emulator) there is a Bus class owning tons of objects thats
    // alive for the whole duration
    let tq = Arc::new(TimerQueue::new());
    let test = Test::new();
    test.do_stuff(&*tq);
    // just to keep everything alive while we wait
    let mut input = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
}
```

cargo toml

```
[package]
name = "tqclient"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
timerqueue = { git = "https://github.com/pm100/timerqueue.git" }
parking_lot = "0.11"
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply define your type as a struct encapsulating an `Arc` with some private state?

Comment: @apetranzilla Well I thought I had a good data design (although I am on the massive rust learining curve) . I have a public object thats Arced, internally it has all its data in a private inner that is mutexed. I dont want to pass my inner data since thats an implementation detail. Anyway I worked out how to do it. Just make my new fn  build the Arc and steal a copy of it for later use (which is what the c++ mixin does)

Comment: The main reason for `enable_shared_from_this` in C++, as far as I can tell, is to be able to access the `shared_ptr` inside methods where `this` is implicit. Rust allows methods to take `self` as an `Arc<Self>` or `&Arc<Self>` explicitly (as Alice's answer shows), so this "feature" isn't really necessary. At least, I couldn't find any example of using it in C++ where it would actually be necessary in Rust; maybe you have something else in mind.

Comment: @trentcl Arc<Self> is the type , it still doesnt let me get at the Arc that refers to me. I need to pass myself to a function so that I can be called back later. I cannot pass a raw 'self' I have to pass *the* Arc that refers to me. I will edit the question to show what I came up with

Comment: Thanks for providing an example. [Here's how I would solve it](https://gist.github.com/trentj/a5acd71ac532b751f675ac8d6244690b) using my variation on Alice's answer.

Comment: However, I do think there is merit to apetranzilla's suggestion just to move the `Arc` inside `Test`, since the `Arc` is itself more or less an implementation detail of `Test` -- you can't have a `Test` without it and you don't really want the user to be able to use, for instance, `Arc::try_unwrap` to get a bare `Test`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to go from a `&self` to the `Arc` that `self` is stored in. This is because:

1. Rust references have additional assumptions compared to C++ references that would make such a conversion undefined behavior.
2. Rust's implementation of `Arc` does not even expose the information necessary to determine whether `self` is stored in an `Arc` or not.

Luckily, there is an alternative approach. Instead of creating a `&self` to the value inside the `Arc`, and passing that to the method, pass the `Arc` directly to the method that needs to access it. You can do that like this:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Shared {
    field: String,
}

impl Shared {
    fn print_field(self: Arc<Self>) {
        let clone: Arc<Shared> = self.clone();
        
        println!("{}", clone.field);
    }
}
```

Then the `print_field` function can only be called on an `Shared` encapsulated in an `Arc`.

Comment: `self: &Arc<Self>` can also be useful, especially if the method does not always need to clone. The tradeoff is an extra layer of indirection.

Comment: thats not what I am trying to do. Using yr names. I have an instance of Shared thats already arced, from a method in that Shared I want to pass the arc of myself to a function. In your example somebody had to call print_field on the Arc of me. Who is doing that call

Comment: It is impossible to go from a `&T` to the `Arc<T>` it is stored in. This conversion can only go one way. My suggestion is to never throw away the `Arc` that you needed in the first place.

Comment: @AliceRyhl I did not throw it away.

Comment: @trentcl this is effectively what I ended up doing. Se my answer its just not trivial to do

Comment: Anyway thanks for the input. I wrote a simple thing that works for me and provides the same functionality. It got silently downvoted for some reason, but it fixes my needs and I assume its safe since it doesn’t use unsafe

Comment: @pm100 Hmm, that's not really what I suggested. The solution in your answer seems unjustified to me because if `nargle` really needs to pass an `Arc<Self>` to `fertang`, then `nargle` should itself be declared as taking `Arc<Self>` (or possibly `&Arc<Self>`). Instead, you're "lying" about `nargle` taking `&self`, and writing incidental code to cover up the lie. In C++ you sometimes *have* to lie, because `this` can only be a pointer, so `shared_from_this` is the solution. In Rust you don't have to lie, so why *wouldn't* you just make `nargle` take `Arc<Self>` explicitly?

Comment: If Alice's answer doesn't work for you, perhaps you should create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem and give the community a chance to chew on it. I can't imagine a non-contrived example where the best answer isn't just "change the type of `self`", but I admit I could be wrong.

Comment: @trentcl nargle is actually this thing here https://github.com/pm100/timerqueue. It is entirely general purpose, it can take a request from any object to run a closure later. Since the closure must be move the object thats selfed into it must be arced.

Comment: @trencl I also dont see how an instance of Self would get an Arc<Self> from inside a method of Self. I mean thats what my code does, if there is simpler code them please put it in an answer

Comment: "I also dont see how an instance of Self would get an Arc<Self> from inside a method of Self" You don't. You would make the other method take `Arc<Self> ` too.

Comment: @pm100 Please provide a [mre]. `timerqueue` compiles successfully and does not appear to have your `MeKeeper` workaround in it so I have no idea what part is relevant.

Comment: @trenctl MeKepper is needed by the caller of timerqueue since timerqueue needs an Arc to create a move closure. I will update the question with a minimal caller example

Answer (score 1):

Alice's answer seems the most logical.

However, `shared_from_this<T>` does not use some under-the-hood C++ magic; it is simply a base class with a `weak_ptr<T>` member. While Rust favours encapsulation and traits over inheritance, there is nothing to prevent us from accomplishing the same.

Unlike `self:Rc<T>`, this is somewhat verbose due to the lack of inheritance. The use case for this method is that we do not need a reference back to the original `Rc`, thus there are fewer compile-time constraints and `&self` may simply be used.

A similar pattern is perhaps more usefully employed by nested child objects to obtain a parent, rather than on a parent to obtain itself.

##### Implementation:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

pub struct SharedFromThisBase<T> {
    weak: RefCell<Weak<T>>,
}

impl<T> SharedFromThisBase<T> {
    pub fn new() -> SharedFromThisBase<T> {
        SharedFromThisBase {
            weak: RefCell::new(Weak::new()),
        }
    }

    pub fn initialise(&self, r: &Rc<T>) {
        *self.weak.borrow_mut() = Rc::downgrade(r);
    }
}

pub trait SharedFromThis<T> {
    fn get_base(&self) -> &SharedFromThisBase<T>;

    fn shared_from_this(&self) -> Rc<T> {
        self.get_base().weak.borrow().upgrade().unwrap()
    }
}
```

##### Contrived example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    base: SharedFromThisBase<MyStruct>,
}

impl SharedFromThis<MyStruct> for MyStruct {
    fn get_base(&self) -> &SharedFromThisBase<MyStruct> {
        &self.base
    }
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new() -> Rc<MyStruct> {
        let r = Rc::new(MyStruct {
            base: SharedFromThisBase::new(),
        });
        r.base.initialise(&r);
        r
    }

    pub fn hello(&self) {
        println!("Hello!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct = MyStruct::new();
    let my_struct_2 = my_struct.shared_from_this();
    my_struct_2.hello();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

having found that I needed this three times in recent days I decided to stop trying to come up with other designs. Maybe poor data design as far as rust is concerned but I needed it.

Works by changing the new function of the types using it to return an Arc rather than a raw self. All my objects are arced anyway, before they were arced by the caller, now its forced.

mini util library called mekeeper

```
use parking_lot::Mutex;
use std::sync::{Arc,Weak};
use std::ops::{DerefMut};


pub struct MeKeeper<T> {
    them: Mutex<Weak<T>>,
}

impl<T> MeKeeper<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            them: Mutex::new(Weak::new()),
        }
    }
    pub fn save(&self, arc: &Arc<T>) {
        *self.them.lock().deref_mut() = Arc::downgrade(arc);
    }
    pub fn get(&self) -> Arc<T> {
        match self.them.lock().upgrade() {
            Some(arc) => return arc,
            None => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
}
```

to use it

```
pub struct Test {
    me: MeKeeper<Self>,
    foo:i8,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn new() -> Arc<Self> {
        let arc = Arc::new(Test {
            me: MeKeeper::new(),
            foo:42
        });
        arc.me.save(&arc);
        arc
    }
}
```

now when an instance of Test wants to call a function that requires it to pass in an Arc it does:

```
 fn nargle(){
     let me = me.get();
     Ooddle::fertang(me,42);// fertang needs an Arc<T>
 }
```

the weak use is what the shared_from_this does so as to prevent refcount deadlocks, I stole that idea.

The unreachable path is safe because the only place that can call MeKeeper::get is the instance of T (Test here) that owns it and that call can only happen if the T instance is alive. Hence no none return from weak::upgrade